# Prove that if $x_n\to x$ and $x > r$, then there exists $K\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geq K\implies x_n > r$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent sequence with limit $x$ and $x>r$.
Is there a $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq  K \implies  x_n > r.$

Comment: It could be better to reformulate your question in the question, not in the title only, so that people can read more conveniently.  Also, LaTex is a good way of formulating your auestion.Thanks.

Comment: @Leong Lyn The question title is supposed to be descriptive. There's nothing against putting the whole question in the title (unless it's too big), but you should definitely write the question in the question body as well.

Comment: Once you've done that: do you know what $x_n \to x$ means?

Comment: @awllower Thanks for the comment, it's my first time posting a math question and so its bound to have errors. :)

Comment: If you ask a question here, you should include what you already **know** and what you have **tried**. This gives us better hints to see where your problems are with that question.

Answer (score 1):

This Statement is true, using the defintion of convergence $$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists K \in \mathbb{N}: |x_n-x|< \varepsilon$$   you get the result by choosing $$\varepsilon = \frac{|x-r|}{2}$$